# Core Data - insertedObjects returns empty set

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Here is my code:

```
WDAlarm *alarm = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WDAlarm"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:[[UTCoreData sharedManager] managedObjectContext]];
```

I am checking the insertedObjects using a breakpoint and:

```
po [[[UTCoreData sharedManager] managedObjectContext] insertedObjects];
```

the result is:

```
{(
)}

{(
)}
```

The UTCoreData is a helper class (instead of adding all core data code inside app delegate). The object alarm is created. According to Apple's documentation right here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/reset the insertedObjects

> Returns the set of objects that have been inserted into the receiver but not yet saved in a persistent store.

which is exactly my case, however it keeps on returning empty set (and the notification `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` is not posted).

**Update 1:** The sharedManager is working fine:

```
(lldb) po [[UTCoreData sharedManager] managedObjectContext] <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x920fff0>

(lldb) po [[UTCoreData sharedManager] managedObjectContext] <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x920fff0>
```

**Update 2:** The code works fine in the production code, not in the XCTestCase. I don't know why it won't although everything is created as expected.

Comment: 18 views with no answers?

Comment: My guess would be that you either have problems with your `sharedManager` returning a new manager on each call, or your `managedObjectContext` method return a new context on each call

Comment: Nope. It returns the same object every time I print it out. Check for the update in the Q. Thanks for the answer though. Any other thoughts? IT's getting me crazy. BTW, this is in XCTestCase, not the production code? could it be the reason?

Comment: @DanShelly I think you are right. For some reason, there are two managedObjectContexts! I am debugging the code now.

Comment: There are some issues (i'm not quite familiar with) with testing and CoreData. I found it easier to setup and teardown the entire stack or mocking it altogether (there is no need for you to test the framework ... unless you test for fixes for known bugs)

Comment: Regarding this method of testing, refer to my comment on Florian below. After a lot of debugging, I couldn't reach anything. The managed context doesn't show the inserted objects although fetching them works. Seems to be some sort of bug in Core Data during testing (or may be with singleton). Any way, I found another way to test the particular case of mine. Thanks @DanShelly

Answer (score 1):

You are running in a classic dependency issue when your unit tests rely on a singleton and you are not testing the singleton itself.

As Dan Shelly already mentioned, unit testing Core Data can be difficult. There are some best practices how to test Core Data. The one that I use in my projects for years is to create a new Core Data stack with an in-memory store in each `setUp` method. Reset/remove the Core Data stack in each `tearDown` method to ensure that you have a fresh and clean stack for each unit test method.

Comment: +1, I followed [this core data set up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1850011/620197) for testing.

Comment: This is one way to test core data code. However, it doesn't work in my situation. My code test the interaction between UTCoreData and a Data Controller. I know this conflicts with the basic principle of Unit Testing. However, I find this way provides more robust application. Also, the code listen to changes in the managed context to update some area. In your way of testing core data, this requires me injecting the  context in the data controller in order to listen to modifications and behaves correctly (which will mess my production code).